# pug mixin input type

Tags: javascript, html, pug

```
mixin input-text(value, type)
    - var type = text
    case type
        when date
            input.form-control(type="date" value=value)
        default
            input.form-control(type=type value=value)
```

Если нет значения аргумента type, то делать просто input text, если есть, то присваивать в зависимости от аргумента

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить значение по умолчанию для аргументов

```
mixin input-text(value, type = 'text')
  input.form-control(type=type value=value)


+input-text('Hello')
+input-text('World', 'date')
```